# Execute SQL Simple Query

Tags: sql, filemaker

I have a simple query that I'm sure anyone whos not a novice will be able to easily solve, I have a table which has a bunch of 'tags' for instagram. I am trying to extract TAGS where DATE = today.

A rough copy of what I want is shown below, I know the syntax is incorrect which is why I'm struggling, but I think you can see what I'm trying to achieve, any advice welcome :)

```
ExecuteSQL 

(  

SELECT IGs::tag 

FROM IGs:: 

WHERE IGs::creation date = 22/10/2048

;)
```

However I would prefer that creation date = $$todaysdate ( I will set the variable before the ExecuteSQL in the script.

Comment: https://community.filemaker.com/thread/164798

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use quotes around the query. Something like this.

```
ExecuteSQL 
(  
    "SELECT tag 
    FROM IGs 
    WHERE \"creation date\" = ?"
    ;"";"";$$todaysdate
)
```

Comment: Andreas coming to my aid once again! I owe you a beer mate! That's cracked it, thankyou once again.

Comment: No problem @Sean, glad to help. Be aware that FileMaker's ExecuteSQL is fragile and breaks easily if you later change a field name or table name. There are many ways to work around that, my favorite way is to use a couple of custom functions that takes advantage of FileMaker's built-in robustness against such things and also handles quotes automatically. More on those [here](https://filemakerhacks.com/2012/05/13/fm-12-executesql-robust-coding-part-1/)